# Shopify - add automatically javascript to template <head>

Tags: shopify

Is it possible to add automatically some js library to template `<head`> section during app installation?

Given I:

1. Downloaded this repo: https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app
2. Edited `config/initializers/shopify_app.rb` and added this line `config.scope = "read_orders, read_products, read_themes, write_themes"`
3. Put this line to the controller: `ShopifyAPI::Asset.create(key: 'assets/angular.js', src: 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js')`
   where `angular.js` is my library.

I am able to use angular in the template but, I must add in the `<head>` section this code `{{ 'angular.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}`.
Can I add this code automatically during app installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under `config/initializers/shopify_app.rb` you must add to csope parameter what permission you need. `config.scope = "read_orders, read_products, read_themes, write_themes, write_script_tags, read_script_tags"` 
In this case we need `write_script_tags`. After that you must add some script from cotroller, for example:

```
st = ShopifyAPI::ScriptTag.new(:src => "https://rawgit.com/someurl/10a5bf06d1b77a871426/raw/40a5c536453783d8b2b5ec3705ec13688bd3407c/widget.js", :event => "onload")
st.save
```

Your js file might look like this one:

```
  (function () {
    'use strict';

    var matches = document.getElementsByTagName("someTag")[0];
    console.log(matches);

  }());
```